# Pydev Eclipse won't allow me rename module

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, rename, pydev

I am trying to rename a module, using a name for a module that was deleted and does not exist any more. However, eclipse thinks that there is conflict in naming. I am sure this is not the case. I cannot even find a reference of that word in the whole workspace directory when I search with grep. What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some .pyc leftover? If you do a Ctrl+SHift+T/Ctrl+R can you find that module/file? (i.e.: if you had a package with an `__init__` that went to the same name that could be an issue)

If that's not the case, you can try to force the refresh of the PyDev indexing (open a PyDev editor and do Ctrl+2 and in the options that appear in the popup later select '--reindex').

If that still fails, please add a screenshot with the pydev package explorer showing the structure of your project and the actual dialog showing the conflict so that I can check if there's something else missing... (in the worse you should be able to revert to a simple rename in the rename option -- although that won't rename dependencies).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed .pyc and it didn't work. Eventually, I ended up performing the renaming operation via Linux terminal(mv old_file_name.py new_file_name.py)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked was renaming the file outside the IDE, through Linux terminal using the mv command:

```
mv old_file_name.py new_file_name.py
```

The cause of the problem is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I found the problem and solution.

I never had this problem until today. I don't what happened but the 'Rename' and 'Move'  options vanished from the right click menu option from the file explorer window. Turns out this menu has an option called 'Show In' which let you choose between Package Explorer, Navigator, System Explorer, among other different ways to explore your files and folders.

I tested each one and found Navigator is the one that has the Rename and Move options when you right click on a file/folder! You can also access them from the main menu > Windows > Show View.